# HTML Validation using PHP

Tags: php, html, validation

I have a number of sites on a server that have multiple employees working on them daily.  As a result of so many people handling these files, it can be hard to keep up with certain things.  I am building a PHP based tool that will scan these pages for things like broken links, spelling errors, and other such things.

Right now I am working on the HTML validation portion of this, namely missing/extra tag close and opens.  I found a post on here ([PHP Based HTML Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349372/php-based-html-validator)) that led me to a pear package that links in with W3C validation.

I have not tried this yet, as the last version released is almost 5 years old.  Can anyone help me get my nose pointed in the right direction.

Comment: While the last version "released" through Pear is almost 5 years old, if you take a look on [the project's GitHub repository](https://github.com/pear/Services_W3C_HTMLValidator) you'll see plenty of recent activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this job PHP has built in function **array libxml_get_errors ( void )** that will return an array of errors. Take a look at [this documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php). There is also an example.

My test with page body:

```
<?php

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xmlstr = <<< XML
    <body>
        <h1>Correct tag</h1>
        <h2>Tag not closed</h2>
        <p>Missing end of paragraph
        <br>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var test = "Script";
        </script>
        <img src="some.url" alt="Image title" >
        <footer>Some error in footer?<footer>
    </body>
XML;

$doc = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
$xml = explode("\n", $xmlstr);

if (!$doc) {
    $errors = array_reverse ( libxml_get_errors() );
    echo "<pre>";
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo display_xml_error($error, $xml);
    }
    echo "</pre>";
    libxml_clear_errors();
}


function display_xml_error($error, $xml)
{
    $return  = $xml[$error->line - 1] . "\n";
    $return .= str_repeat('-', $error->column) . "^\n";

    switch ($error->level) {
        case LIBXML_ERR_WARNING:
            $return .= "Warning $error->code: ";
            break;
         case LIBXML_ERR_ERROR:
            $return .= "Error $error->code: ";
            break;
        case LIBXML_ERR_FATAL:
            $return .= "Fatal Error $error->code: ";
            break;
    }

    $return .= trim($error->message);

    if ($error->file) {
        $return .= "\n  File: $error->file";
    }

    return "$return\n\n--------------------------------------------\n\n";
}

?>
```

Results with:

```
---------^
Fatal Error 77: Premature end of data in tag body line 1

--------------------------------------------

    
---------^
Fatal Error 77: Premature end of data in tag p line 4

--------------------------------------------

    
---------^
Fatal Error 77: Premature end of data in tag br line 5

--------------------------------------------

    
---------^
Fatal Error 77: Premature end of data in tag img line 9

--------------------------------------------

    
---------^
Fatal Error 77: Premature end of data in tag footer line 10

--------------------------------------------

    
---------^
Fatal Error 76: Opening and ending tag mismatch: footer line 10 and body

--------------------------------------------
```

Do not be confused with error for **body** not closed. In case HTML is valid, than there are no errors dropped. For example, the following code has no errors according to **array libxml_get_errors()**:

```
<body>
    <h1>Correct tag</h1>
    <h2>Tag closed</h2>
    <p>Not missing end of paragraph</p>
<br />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var test = "Script";
    </script>
        <img src="some.url" alt="Image title" />
        <div class="somediv">
            <p>Paragraph nested</p> 
            <ul>
                <li>List element</li>
                <li>List element</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <footer>No error in footer</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: this gave me what i need to get started on investigating and tweaking this to meet my needs.  thank you!

Comment: HTML should be well formed, so for broken tags it works fine. Take a look at the small test I made above.

Comment: Well, yes, but for example `<p>This is a paragraph.<p>This is another paragraph</p>` is valid, well-formed HTML5, as HTML5 doesn't follow the XML rules. Paragraphs can be considered closed when a new paragraph comes along, and that's perfectly valid according to the spec.

Comment: It is important he gets all the warnings, he can ignore paragraph, list, body, break tags...

Answer (score 0):

I have a validation app that runs multiple validations.

**First I check the page for basic parameters and server configuration.**

Parameters that in range, printout Green, out of range: Red, in between: Yellow

```
Web Server Configuration
Base Page HTML
Compression enabled: Yes
Cache specified: Yes max-age=31536000, public
Expiration specified: Yes
Keep Alive Specified: Yes
Characterset Specified: Yes
Web Server Performance Metrics
Base Page HTML
Base Page Size: 17,126 Bytes
Transmission Speed: 2,137,041 Bytes/Sec.
Compression: 1.9X
HTML Whitespace: 0.0%
Bytes Transmitted: 9,029 Bytes
HTML Transfer Rate: 4,053,491 Bytes/Sec.
Resolve Domain Name: 0.107 Sec.
Connect Time: 0.107
Transfer Time: 0.004 Sec.
Generate HTML: 0.195 Sec.
Total Time: 0.307 Sec.
```

**Then I run these 4 Validation Tools with curl.**

- W3C HTML Markup
- W3C CSS Validation Service
- W3C mobileOK Checker
- Web Page Test

Then report the results like:

- No CSS Errors
- No HTML Errors
- W3C mobileOK 96%
- Page Speed Score: 99%

Comment: I actually have built the spell check and link checker already using curl to check the http_code, and curl with the built in enchant library to check the words on the page.  I just need to figure out the validation side of it.

Comment: How does this answer the question exactly?