# How to get if a string Is correctly formatted with HTML tags

Tags: php, html, format

I want to verify if a string is correctly formatted with HTML Tags.
For example:

```
    "<b>This Is wrong"
```

This Is the function I used.

```
function closetags($html) { 

 preg_match_all('#<([a-z]+)(?: .*)?(?<![/|/ ])>#iU', $html, $result); $openedtags = $result[1];

   preg_match_all('#</(([a-z])+)>#iU', $html, $result); $closedtags = $result[1]; $len_opened = count($openedtags); 

   if (count($closedtags) == $len_opened) { return true; } else { return false;}
}
```

I've already tried to use this but when the string Is:

```
"<B>This is correct</>"
```

It doesn't work..

Thank you in advance
Francesco

Comment: Have you checked this out? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349372/php-based-html-validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349372/php-based-html-validator)

Comment: Yes, but It wasn't what I want. I want only check if all html tags (for format e.x bold, italic) are closed.